# long hrefs that run off page both in text and in the citations, how do I prevent this?

Tags: bibliographies, url

I have long urls that appear to get cutoff both in text and in the citations.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[letterpaper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

url with no hyphens that is long and already starts halfway across the page \href{http://sadlkjfdlkabfskalbjflskdbgfksldabvladbcviuldasbcalsuncilsalxbvucx.com/}{http://sadlkjfdlkabfskalbjflskdbgfksldabvladbcviuldasbcalsuncilsalxbvucx.com/}

random citation \cite{zotero-180}

\bibliographystyle{naturemag}

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{sample}

\end{document}
```

my bib file:

```
@misc{zotero-180,
  title = {{{this long citation also appears in bib gets cut}}},
  file = {C\:\\Users\\myfile.html},
  howpublished = {http://sadlkjfdlkabfskalbjflskdbgfksldabvladbcviuldasbcalsuncilsalxbvucx.com/}
}
```

Comment: To typeset URLs directly, use `\url` as in `\href{http://sadlkjfdlkabfskalbjflskdbgfksldabvladbcviuldasbcalsuncilsalxbvucx.com/}`. This already allows URLs to break in some places (at punctuation), but your example URL will probably still not break nicely, since it contains a long passage without punctuation. In that case you can additionally load the package `xurl` (`\usepackage{xurl}`), which allows line breaks everywhere.

Comment: Note that two `\bibliographystyle`s are invalid. You can only have one `\bibliographystyle` call. You probably want to use `\url` in `howpublished` as well if your bibliography style does not support a `url` field: `howpublished = {\url{http://sadlkjfdlkabfskalbjflskdbgfksldabvladbcviuldasbcalsuncilsalxbvucx.com/}},`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you can simply load package `xurl` like this:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{zotero-180,
  title = {{{this long citation also appears in bib gets cut}}},
  file = {C\:\\Users\\myfile.html},
  howpublished = {\url{http://sadlkjfdlkabfskalbjflskdbgfksldabvladbcviuldasbcalsuncilsalxbvucx.com/}},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{xurl} % <===================================================
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

url with no hyphens that is long and already starts halfway across the page 
\url{http://sadlkjfdlkabfskalbjflskdbgfksldabvladbcviuldasbcalsuncilsalxbvucx.com/} % <===============

random citation \cite{zotero-180}

%\bibliographystyle{naturemag} % <======================================

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Please see that I used `\url` instead your used `\href{}{}` to get `xurl` working.

The resulting pdf is:

[image]

Comment: this really helped me thank you!

Comment: @curious You are welcome!